# Will Linux kernel verifies if source MAC and IP are match in ICMP request?

Tags: networking, icmp

I have following configuration of the systems:
[image]

When I issued ping 192.168.1.200 form Switch, I found the ICMP request packet's source IP in IP header is 1.1.1.2 but the source MAC in L2 header is MAC2, the packets are sent through Port2 to Eth1. In this case there's no ICMP reply from CentOS.
However if the IP and MAC in ICMP request are all Port2's(using option in ping command to designated), CentOS will reply correctly.

I suspect in the first case, some verification work is done by the kernel and the packets are dropped because of the mismatch. But I cannot find the proof. Does anyone know this? If this is the case, may  the related source routine pointed out if possible. Thanks a lot!

The Kernel version of CentOS is 3.10.0.

```
network settings as following:
============================Cent7.x============================
[root@CentOS ~]# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 1.1.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 1.1.1.255
        inet6 fe80::201:edff:fefc:56fa  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:01:ed:fc:56:fa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 139  bytes 16868 (16.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 44  bytes 5324 (5.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 2.2.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 2.2.2.255
        inet6 fe80::201:edff:fefc:56fb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:01:ed:fc:56:fb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 250  bytes 31688 (30.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 68  bytes 7524 (7.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.202  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::201:edff:fefc:56fc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:01:ed:fc:56:fc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3000  bytes 500249 (488.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9054  bytes 12030772 (11.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[root@CentOS ~]# ip route
1.1.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 1.1.1.1 metric 100 
2.2.2.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 2.2.2.1 metric 101 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.202 metric 102 
[root@CentOS ~]# 
[root@CentOS ~]# arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
1.1.1.2                  ether   12:31:23:12:31:2f   C                     eth0
2.2.2.2                  ether   12:31:23:12:31:41   C                     eth1
192.168.1.150            ether   a0:36:9f:a0:d9:6e   C                     eth2

============================Switch============================
[lsw]ip routing-table:

Destinations : 17       Routes : 18

Destination/Mask   Proto   Pre Cost        NextHop         Interface
0.0.0.0/32         Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
1.1.1.0/24         Direct  0   0           1.1.1.2         Vlan2
1.1.1.0/32         Direct  0   0           1.1.1.2         Vlan2
1.1.1.2/32         Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
1.1.1.255/32       Direct  0   0           1.1.1.2         Vlan2
2.2.2.0/24         Direct  0   0           2.2.2.2         Vlan20
2.2.2.0/32         Direct  0   0           2.2.2.2         Vlan20
2.2.2.2/32         Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
2.2.2.255/32       Direct  0   0           2.2.2.2         Vlan20
127.0.0.0/8        Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
127.0.0.0/32       Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
127.0.0.1/32       Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
127.255.255.255/32 Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0
192.168.1.202/32   Static  50  0           1.1.1.1         Vlan2
                                           2.2.2.1         Vlan20
224.0.0.0/4        Direct  0   0           0.0.0.0         NULL0
224.0.0.0/24       Direct  0   0           0.0.0.0         NULL0
255.255.255.255/32 Direct  0   0           127.0.0.1       InLoop0

[lsw]arp
  Type: S-Static   D-Dynamic   O-Openflow   R-Rule   M-Multiport  I-Invalid
IP address      MAC address    VLAN/VSI name Interface                Aging Type
1.1.1.1         0001-edfc-56fa 2             XGE1/1/1                 293   D   
2.2.2.1         0001-edfc-56fb 20            XGE1/1/2                 724   D
```

Comment: You make an assumption and want to stick to it. What if that was something else? Like the route using the wrong interface? You should provide your network settings (using low level commands: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route`).

Comment: tcpdump caprutred those icmp requests in Eth1, but after that I found icmp related statistics in "netstat -s" was not changed. This let me think those packets are dropped due to some verification failure.

Comment: I still don't see your network settings in the question.

Comment: network settings added.